# HUDSON workspace is wiped out autometically?

Tags: svn, hudson

I have configured jobs in HUDSON (Version 2.2.1) and whenever these jobs triggers and completes, I found the workspace is wiped out and it is a blank with below error message and build will successfully completes without any issue (only workspace is wiped out).

*-------------------------------------------------
**Error: no workspace**
There's no workspace for this project. Possible reasons are:
The project was renamed recently and no build was done under the new name.
The slave this project has run on for the last time was removed.
The workspace directory (null) is removed outside Hudson.
Run a build to have Hudson create a workspace.
----------------------------------------------------------*

**Please note:**
1. Recently, I have renamed these jobs.
2. I have verified the configuration of these jobs and NO WHERE I have used the options which will wipe-out (cleans) the workspace for e.g. I have not enable or checked the options like "**Clean workspace before build" or "Clean workspace after build" etc** and I am not executing any shell scripts or cmds that will clean the workspace.

Under Source Code Management--> the Check-out Strategy I have used is **"Use 'svn update'as much as possible”.**

**My build log starts with below message:**
Started by upstream project "8.6.0.0_xxx_Build" build number 77 Building remotely on xxxx_xxxx_slave5_linux
Checking out a fresh workspace because /scratch/hudson/slave/workspace/8.6.0.0_xxxx_Job/src doesn't exist
Cleaning workspace /scratch/hudson/slave/workspace/8.6.0.0_xxx_Job
………………………………..so on……………………………………etc

Please advise ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

on hudson system property set hudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.disabled = true.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the help. I think this is a global property and if it's the global propert, why are not all jobs workspaces in Hudson wiped out? Only particular set of HUDSON jobs workspace are wiped out (i.e. I have this issue after renaming the HUDSON jobs and I did ran these jobs on the slave to have Hudson create a workspace). Please advise.

Comment: is there something on the console log of the job that can help?
I would try changing the sys property although you are right

Comment: Please find workspace-clean-up.log output****************Scanning everest_slc01qbz_slave1_linux
Scanning sanford_slc03sdw_slave10_windows
Scanning blue_ridge_slc03rvn_slave11_linux
Deleting /scratch/software/hudson/jobs/8.5.0.0_IM_Base_Stack/workspace
Deleting /scratch/software/hudson/jobs/8.5.0.0_Infra_Build/workspace
Deleting /scratch/software/hudson/jobs/8.5.0.0_Search_Artifacts_Build/workspace
Deleting /scratch/software/hudson/jobs/8.5.0.0_Installer_Build/workspace
Deleting /scratch/software/hudson/jobs/8.5.0.0_App_Artifacts_Build/workspace

Comment: Below is the console output:*******************************13:57:58  Started by user xxxxxx
13:57:58  Building remotely on slave9_linux
13:58:00  Checking out a fresh workspace because /scratch/hudson/slave/workspace/8.6.0.0_IM_Base_Stack/src doesn't exist
13:58:00  Cleaning workspace /scratch/hudson/slave/workspace/8.6.0.0_IM_Base_Stack
13:58:00  Checking out https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    *********Checking out the code*********14:00:55  A         internal/build.xml
14:00:56  At revision 57664
14:00:56  no revision recorded for https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8.6.0.0/src in the previous build

Comment: Console output part2:***********************14:02:22  + echo 'Total number of files under build direcotory for 8.6.0.0_IM_Base_Stack:'
14:02:22  Total number of files under build direcotory for 8.6.0.0_IM_Base_Stack:
14:02:22  + ls -lrtR /net/slc03rrg/scratch/hudson/slave/workspace/8.6.0.0_IM_Base_Stack/src/build/
14:02:22  + wc -l
14:02:22  928
14:02:22  Archiving artifacts
14:02:46  Performing Post build task...
14:02:46  Could not match :EXIT_CODE 1  : False
14:02:46  Logical operation result is FALSE

Comment: Console output part3:**************14:02:46  
14:02:46  find garbage excution step here
14:02:46  END OF POST BUILD TASK  : 0
14:02:46  Checking console output
14:02:46  Triggering a new build of 8.6.0.0_iConnect_RightNow_CSharp_DLL #66
14:02:46  Triggering a new build of Clear_Archives_Directories #8170
14:02:46  [DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update; build not configured with trigger: 8.6.0.0_IM_Base_Stack #70
14:02:46  Notifying upstream projects of job completion
14:02:46  Finished: SUCCESS